# Proving a sequence is not Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I want to prove that a sequence is not Cauchy by proving something like
$$ \exists \epsilon >0 \space s.t \space \space \forall n_0 \in N \space \space \exists n, n+p > n_0 \space=>  |x_{n+p} - x_n| > \epsilon $$

For that specific question I think I can prove that by taking sequences $$x_n, x_{n+3}$$ as an example plugging that into sequence formula, however I am not sure if it is even allowed to take a specific number for the p in a proof. Can you please clarify that part?

The sequence I am trying to prove is not Cauchy is:
$$x_n = {3n+1 \over n+4}sin{2\pi n \over 3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Watch out:

Negating an implies symbol does NOT give another implies symbol.

That arrow should be an and symbol, or something with equivalent meaning.

You are allowed to take specific numbers for p: 3 is fine ,as if $n>n_0$, then certainly $n+3>n_0$, so that's OK!.

Comment: +1 The first two sentences here nicely address an important error buried in the question. That kind of error is more easily avoided if you write out sentences with more words and fewer symbols.